# WordPress shows only posts from one category

Tags: wordpress, categories

I have a simple WordPress installation in my test site. I have no plugins and no special code to exclude (or include) categories in my pages (nothing special for this in **functions.php**)

I have posts in my categories "people", "projects". However, only posts from my category "places" are visible. What's more, if I go to http://[my-test-site]/category/people, I see nothing displayed in the following code (I have a "category-people/php" page)

```
$categories = get_the_category();
$category = $categories[0]->slug;
echo '<br/>the category is:' . $category . "<br/>";
```

The same code above in my **front-page.php** shows the category as "places". This is very strange. I expect the front-page.php to have no categories (I am not including or excluding any categories by any code or plugin)

Could someone please help me understand what's going on? I've tried changing the **WordPress Permalinks Settings** to all possible, but it still doesn't work. This is my **.htaccess** file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Any help please? I'm getting desperate and seriously behind schedule on my assignment.

Thanks!
Anjaan

Answer (score 0):

You getting just first category slug with `$categories[0]->slug`.
You should to get all categories slug from the loop, like:

```
foreach( get_the_category() as $category ){ 
  echo '<br/>the category is:'.$category->slug."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I know this loop will give all categories. However, when I am in the category page itself, I want only the first (and only) category, not all. Also, in the front-page.php, the loop above gives only one category. How can I get the current category in a category.php page?